# How do i use WHERE with different tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Nome FROM Fornecedores 
WHERE ForneceArtigos.codArtigo = Artigos.codArtigo AND Modelo = 'keys';
```

I know this is not possible the way i made so i wanted to know a way that is possible to do this.

[image]

I hope you understood what i meant.

Comment: You’ll need to use joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT Nome 
FROM Fornecedores 
JOIN ForneceArtigos ON Fornecedores.codForn = ForneceArtigos.codForn
JOIN Artigos ON ForneceArtigos.codArtigo = Artigos.codArtigo
WHERE Artigos.Modelo = 'keys';
```

Comment: Yea it's just like you did. Thank you really much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If i undestood should be:

```
SELECT Nome FROM Fornecedores a, Artigos b WHERE a.codArtigo = b.codArtigo AND b.Modelo = 'keys';
```

or, depending on what Mysql you are using, but the image seems fomr Microsoft Access:

```
SELECT Nome FROM Fornecedores a INNER JOIN Artigos b on a.codArtigo = b.codArtigo AND b.Modelo = 'keys';
```

Comment: Do you see this column `codArtigo` on `Fornecedores` table?

Comment: Oh... didn't noticed there codArtigo was not in Fornecedores.... so yuo have first to join Fornecedores with ForneceArtigos throw the codForn, then to Artigos trhowght codArtigo

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to tell that `a.codForn = b.codForn`, but thank you for the help.